# Force a x-axis order in a line plot with strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to make a line plot in which on the x-axis I have strings that correspond to categories, however, I can't seem to sort the x-axis from smallest to largest because I can't seem to force sort of the axis.

```
d = {'Average_Age': [22, 34, 49, 61], 'Salary_Category': 
   ['[1200, 2000[', '[2000, 6500[', '[6500, 10000[', '[11000, 15000]']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

test = sns.lineplot(x= 'Salary_Category' , y= 'Average_Age', data = df)
plt.title('Average Salaries per Age Category')
plt.xlabel('Salary Category')
plt.ylabel('Average Age')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

So this is the plot that I get,  which doesn't make sense since the. salary categories are mixed up. 
   [image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: If you're willing to not use seaborn: pandas does it via `df.set_index("Salary_Category").plot()`, also matplotlib does it via `plt.plot("Salary_Category", 'Average_Age', data=df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by plotting against the row number, and change the ticks label:

```
test = sns.lineplot(np.arange(len(df)) , df['Average_Age'])
plt.title('Average Salaries per Age Category')
plt.xlabel('Salary Category')
plt.ylabel('Average Age')

# set the ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)),rotation=45)

# rename the ticks
test.set_xticklabels(df.Salary_Category)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works thanks! But how would this work if you the salary categories  repeat? For example if I have a column in the Dataframe for males and females that I want to use for the hue. By using this code the x-axis would just repeat side by side instead of the lines appearing on top of each other

Comment: You probably want to pivot your dataframe and use the solution given in the comment.